# Meteor Force Rerender of Handlebar Helpers

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, handlebars.js

In Meteor, I have a navigation bar with a custom handlebar method that determines whether or not the tab is active.

JS:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getClass',function(a){
    url = document.URL.split("/"); //e.g. http://test.com/something, so 3rd value will have link thing
    url = "/" + url[3];
    val = Router.path(a);
    return url == val ? "active" : "";
});
```

HTML Snippet:

```
  <li class="{{getClass 'homepage'}}"><a href="{{pathFor 'homepage'}}">Home</a></li>
  <li class="{{getClass 'content'}}"><a href="{{pathFor 'content'}}">Content</a></li>
  <li class="{{getClass 'items'}}"><a href="{{pathFor 'items'}}">Items</a></li>
```

This sets the appropriate `active` class on a nav-block if I open an entirely new tab, navigating to something like `http://localhost:3000/content`. However, it won't update the `active` class if I merely click a new tab. For instance, from the home page to the `content` page. However, if I click the `items` tab and then click another tab, it will update, but just once. So if I go to the items tab, `items` will have the active class and the next class I click will then get it, removing it from `items`. This only works once, unfortunately. I think it is because `items` has content from a DB, but I'm not sure. Anyways, I need a way to rerender handlebar helpers, if this is at all possible.

I've tried using the following JS to no avail:

```
Content = {};
Content._dep = new Deps.Dependency;

Template.header.events({
  'click a': function () {
      console.log('abc');
    Content._dep.changed();
  }  
})
```

Does anybody have a way to rerender the handlebars without having to physically *reload* the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it. Basically, I added a session with a random number, and updated that on click. It seemed to have done the trick.

Updated code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getClass',function(a){
    url = document.URL.split("/"); //e.g. http://test.com/something, so 3rd value will have link thing
    url = "/" + url[3];
    val = Router.path(a);
    if(Session.get('r'))
        void(0);
    return url == val ? "active" : "";
});


Template.header.events({
  'click a': function () {
      Session.set('r', Math.random() + "");
  }  
})
```

Comment: upvoted because it solved my problem too, but this feels a little too dirty to incorporate permanently. Have you found anything else since posting this to fix this?

Comment: what happens if unfortunately the same number is created?

Comment: I feel like the probability of that is extremely negligible, but it's still a valid critique. (Disclaimer: Haven't coded with Meteor in 3 years and a lot's changed since then.) One potential option would be to simply increment the `r` session param.